# Homeomorphism and Mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra

Having some trouble understanding this:

$(S,\circ)$ and $(J,\times)$ be two groups and $f\colon S \to J$ be a homeomorphism. Prove that $f$ maps the identity of $S$ to the identity in $J$.

Any guides on where to step first. Feeling lost.

Comment: This is a really easy question, somebody is probably already nearly done with an answer (or a close because of duplicate) - what have you tried so far? If you get no answer in 30 mins reply to this comment with "@alecteal" somewhere in it.

Comment: Assuming you mean a *homo*morphism and not a *homeo*morphism, try expanding the identity with itself.

Comment: Not sure. I am pretty confused... @alecteal. I had already been looking at this for a while. I'm new to abstract algebra.

Comment: @user3094000 I've answered.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: @BenWest it's your standard "you have two groups, show a homomorphism maps the identity to the identity in the other group"

Comment: @AlecTeal I know, the groups $S$ and $J$ were introduced, but the codomain of $f$ was $M$. It's been fixed now.

Comment: @BenWest it doesn't really matter because it's clear what he meant to ask, but sure.

Comment: Thanks guys, those comments really helped. And the solutions below. Which is a better proof?

Comment: They're both proofs. One uses a definition, the other uses cancellation laws. @John shows $f(e)$ must be the identity. I show it must be equal to the identity. Which as it is unique shows it must be the identity. You should upvote both

Comment: @AlecTeal makes sense. I read through them. I like how the both differ. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(e)=f(ee)=f(e)f(e)$
But $f(e)=e_Mf(e)$ so we have:
$$f(e)f(e)=e_Mf(e)$$
But recall the [cancellation laws](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Group#Cancellation_laws), $ax=bx \implies a=b$
We have $f(e)f(e)=e_Mf(e)\implies f(e)=e_M$ as required.
This completes the proof.

Comment: Ok I believe I understand that.

Answer (score -1):

$f(g) = f(e\circ g) = f(e)\times f(g)$ and  $f(g) = f(g\circ e) = f(g)\times f(e)$

this is true for all $g\in S$ thus $f(e)$ has to be the identiy of $J$

Answer (score -1):

Note that as soon as Alec Teal writes:

"$f(e) = f(ee) = f(e)f(e)$" we are done.

Why? because of the following theorem:

For any $a \in G$, where $G$ is a group, if $a^2 = a$, then $a = e$.

To see this (it's quite basic), suppose that:

$a^2 = a$.

Multiply both sides on the left (or the right) by $a^{-1}$:

$(a^{-1})(a^2) = a^{-1}a$.

Now $a^2 = aa$, and by associativity, we have:

$(a^{-1})(a^2) = a^{-1}(aa) = (a^{-1}a)a$.

So now we have the equation:

$(a^{-1}a)a = a^{-1}a$, that is:

$ea = e$ and so:

$a = e$.

Note that *only the identity* of a group has this property, and since $f(e)$ is an element of $J$ with this property, it must be the identity of $J$.

This gives you a quick way to verify whether or not you have a group's identity element: multiply it by itself (using the group operation), and see if it stays the same.